# Android: GoogleAuthUtil.getToken - where is the account object supposed to come from?

Tags: android, google-authentication, google-signin, googlesigninaccount, oauth-2.0

GoogleAuthUtil.getToken requires for it's second parameter an account object, but when you connect with Google SignIn what you get back in the result is a GoogleSignInAccount - which isn't the same thing. Is there a way to convert the GoogleSignInAccount to an Account object?

```
 private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            googleSignInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();

        }
    }
```

then later:

```
authToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, [need an account here], scope);
```

I know that I can get the email address back by displaying the accountpicker, and I can also get the email address from the google signin result - but I can't see a way to get the entire account object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker) you can see that the response has KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME and KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE.  Therefore you can create your own [Account object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html)

Code:

```
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
            // Receiving a result from the AccountPicker
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                mType = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                // With the account name acquired, go get the auth token
                Account account = new Account(mEmail, mType);
                String token =  GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account, mScope);
            }
```